# Ficheiros duplicados

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa Tarde,

Sou muito novo no Python (2 meses) e este é o meu primeiro post aqui! 
Estou a criar um script que me ajude a ler dois ficheiros:

-- Ficheiro 1 com 51 linhas (cada linha tem um TSAT113806 diferente)

-- Ficheiro 2 com 58 linhas ( cada linha tem um TSAT113806 igual ao do ficheiro 1 e 7 diferentes)

O que quero fazer é criar um script que me diga:

- quais os números que são repetidos no ficheiro 1 e 2
- grave esse números num ficheiro 3.

Fiz este código, mas não estou a ter resultado, podem-me ajudar sff?

```
import os
def NovoDoc():

    with open('Pedentes.csv', 'r') as pendente:
        arq1: int = pendente.readlines()

    with open('Cancelados.csv' , 'r') as cancelamentos:
        arq2: int = cancelamentos.readlines()

    if arq1 == arq2:
        with open(os.path.join('resultado.csv', 'w')) as res:
            r: int = res.write(arq1)
    else:
        print('Erro')
```

Comment: vc esta a meio caminho, o erro que mais chama atenção é 'arq1: int =', deveria ser 'arq1=', sem os dois pontos e o int

Comment: Olá @EltonNunes, obrigado pela dica.. O que acontece é que eu faco run e depois nao acontece nada! Estou meio perdido ai!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('Pedentes.csv') as pendente:                                          
    arq1 = pendente.readlines()

with open('Cancelados.csv') as cancelamentos:
    arq2 = cancelamentos.readlines()

with open('resultado.csv', 'w') as res:
    for i in arq1:
        for y in arq2:
            if arq1 in arq2:
                    res.write(arq1 + '\n')
                    print('valor escrito')
            else:
                print('Erro')
```

por padrão open usa 'r', então quando for ler um arquivo não vai precisar colocar o 'r'

**open(arq, 'r')** é o mesmo que **open(arq)**

talvez vc esta confundindo o cabeçalho de uma função com a definição de uma variavel

**variavel = valor**

roda a vez que vc chama **open(arq, 'w')**, ele vai sobre escrever o aquivo e vc perdera todo seu contudo, então use apenas uma vez, só feche o arquivo depois de terminar de escrever tudo oq necessita

**.readlines()** retorna uma lista que vc pode usar um loop par percorrer ela

**arq1 == arq2** esta comparando o arquivo em um todo, e não linhas individuais

Comment: Ola @Elton Nunes, obrigado pelo seu comentário, o seu códgio de facto funciona, mas quando faço print (no juyter notebook) ele dá erro!. Reparei que ele cria de facto o ficheiro Resultado mas nao imprime nada no ficheiro. Será que estou a fazer alguma coisa mal? Obrigado pela tua ajuda mais um vez.

Comment: oq vc esta printando? e como vc esta fazendo isso?

Comment: Depois eu fiz isto 
res = open ('resultado.csv', 'r')
resultado = res.read()
res.close()

print(resultado)

Para ver o resultado, e ter entao os numeros repetidos.

Comment: fiz uma alteração no script, ele vai fazer um print cada vez que escrever no arquivo, rode ele para ver se esta escrevendo